# Where can I find a complete skill tree with links to skill info?

Tags: eve-online

I'm looking for a complete skill tree, preferably with a mouseover/link/etc. that shows the details of each skill.  The certification planner is somewhat helpful, but I'm looking for something a little more "big picture".

Comment: What did you want a skill tree for? The skill tree in EVE is very flat and broad.

Comment: Certifications focus on fairly small groups of skills and don't make the overlap between different areas very clear. I feel that a complete skill tree would be better for "big picture" long-term planning. For example, finding different "jobs" or skill groups that share skills, in the short and long term. This seems pretty vital since getting skills past level 3 or so can take days or weeks.

Comment: What overlap between which different areas?  For any given task, there's a small number of related skills.  The relation is shown in certifications.  There is no 'bigger picture' here.  Do you have a single example of what you're talking about?  /me Confused!

Comment: I think the relationship you are looking for, outside of certificates, is the "recommended" tab on ships and modules which points you to groups of certificates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[EveMon](http://evemon.battleclinic.com/) has a pretty good skill tree in it, but it's hard to see everything at once. I don't think I've seen a "complete skill tree" anywhere. But I haven't looked too hard.

Comment: I haven't seen them any better than in EveMon. The problem is that there are so many skills and dependencies. I think putting all of that into one picture would be too confusing anyway.

Comment: I think i already saw a full tree... But i does remember it looking more like a blob... i'll try to find the link =)

Comment: [I found it!](http://go-dl.eve-files.com/media/0802/skillchart.png) But i hope you have a extremely large screen... (not sure it's totally up to date, though...) (EDIT: it's not up to date... no PI skills, still the learning skills... i'll try to look for a recent version)